# How to use a docker executable of highest version installed by nix in bash?

Tags: bash, nix

Via `nix` I have a number of docker executables installed on my local machine.

Here is an example:

```
/nix/store/dbq6mzbsgwv1rnzc52qjbaf33gsfn51z-docker-19.03.4/bin/docker
/nix/store/dbq6mzbsgwv1rnzc52qjbaf33gsfn51z-docker-19.03.4/libexec/docker
/nix/store/dbq6mzbsgwv1rnzc52qjbaf33gsfn51z-docker-19.03.4/libexec/docker/docker
/nix/store/dbq6mzbsgwv1rnzc52qjbaf33gsfn51z-docker-19.03.4/share/bash-completion/completions/docker
/nix/store/fhhly0rgbygghhfmwmdkacrh6cvg6hvg-user-environment/bin/docker
/nix/store/fhhly0rgbygghhfmwmdkacrh6cvg6hvg-user-environment/libexec/docker
/nix/store/fhhly0rgbygghhfmwmdkacrh6cvg6hvg-user-environment/share/bash-completion/completions/docker
```

I want to able to reuse the `docker` installed by `nix` for my dev work. One of the reasons is that the inhouse toolchain relies on a particular version of docker. If I install `Docker for Mac` I will run into runtime exception.

Is there neat nix command line trick such I can get the path to the highest version of docker?  e.g. in the example above I want to use the `docker` executable under `dbq6mzbsgwv1rnzc52qjbaf33gsfn51z-docker-19.03.4`. Ideally, I would like to use something like `$(nix find-path docker)/bin/docker` to invoke the 19.03.04 docker.

I tried `nix run docker` or `nix dump-path docker` but of course they are not the right subcommands.

I want to avoid maintaining another BASH variable to hold a hardcoded path to 19.03.04 docker, because my project might upgrade the docker runtimes from time to time.

Comment: At least 2 of those (under `bash-completion`) aren't actually docker executables. They are the completion functions used by `bash` to complete arguments to the `docker` command.

Comment: And your listing contains two packages, only the first of which is the *actual* `docker` package; the other appears to be a collection of configurations. How did you generate that list?

Comment: `find /nix -name docker`

Comment: That just finds every path in the store with the name `docker` in it; it doesn't show you different versions of the same package.